# What is the docker run path to execute a file?

Tags: docker

Following a code repository the instructions say:

```
docker run -v TikTokApi --rm tiktokapi:latest python3 your_script.py
```

I have the file in the working directory

```
./your_script.py
```

However I get the error:
can't open file 'your_script.py' [Error 2] No such file or directory

I realize that the file is outside of the actual docker container therefore I probably can't access it with
your_script.py
or ./your_script.py

How can I get it to execute the file?

Comment: Use the [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command to copy the file into the container during the build process. Then use [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) if you want to start it when the container starts.